# Nested arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

Looking at the following code,  does `theme[sprite].img` get nested inside `result[definition].data` (as `theme[sprite].img` is inside `theme[sprite]`) as well as `.img` becoming its own element in `result[definition]`?

```
result[definition].data = theme[sprite];
result[definition].img = theme[sprite].img;
```

And if that is the case, what would happen if `result[definition].data.img` was deleted, would that also delete `result[definition].img` and even `theme[sprite].img`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you delete `result[definition].data.img`, then `theme[sprite].img` will be deleted too, because `result[definiton].data` and `theme[sprite]` are exactly the same single object. `result[definition].img` will retain its value beacuse `result[definition]` is separate object that have in its `.img` property copy of `.img` from another object.

This is not related in any way to nesting though. You simply reference the same object.

Comment: Why is 'result[definition].img' a copy? Isn't it a reference to the same object as 'theme[sprite].img;'?

Comment: If img is object, then yes. But you never modify object stored in img, you only modify (delete property) object that is referenced by result[definition].data and theme[sprite]. You do not touch object that might be stored in .img in any way.

Comment: I see. For some reason I thought that if and object that contained a reference to another object was deleted, then that contained referenced object would also be deleted. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> if `result[definition].data.img` was deleted, would that also delete `result[definition].img`...

No. Objects are reference types. While the deletion will be observed from `theme[sprite]`  , it will *not* be observed from `result[definition]`.

Because `theme[sprite]` and `result[definition].data` are references to the same object, any changes made to that object are observable from any reference to it.

But because `result[definition].img` is a reference to a different object that happens to be referenced by the other, it is an entirely unique reference, and isn't affected by what happens in the other object.

---

```
       +-----------+         +-----------+
       |           | sprite  |           |
 theme |           |-------->|           |\    v---deleting this reference...
       |           |         |           | \
       +-----------+         +-----------+  \  img   +-----------+
                                   ^         \       |           |
                                  /           \----> |           |
                                 /                   |           |
                                /                    +-----------+
                   definition  /                           ^
                              /                           /
       +-----------+         /                           /
       |           |        /                           /
result |           |-------/                 img       /
       |           |----------------------------------/
       +-----------+
        ...doesn't affect this one-----------^
           and vice versa
```

If you delete one of the `img` properties, the other stays intact.

Comment: Nice diagram, though it does make it look like the object attached to sprite/definition belongs to sprite, where (correct me if I'm wrong) the object is equally belonging to definition. I understand there is only so much that can be done with ascii diagrams :) Thanks

Comment: @Exceii: Good point. I may try to tweak it a bit as an exercise in my markdown diagram skills. :) But you're right, the rightmost object is no more or less owned by one object than by another. They're identical references.

Answer (score 1):

The answers from Oleg and Cliffs are correct. However, I thought it might be useful, for the purposes of visualization, to see what these objects are actually shaped like:

```
var definition = "Foo",
    sprite     = "Bar",

    result = {},
    theme  = {}
;

result[ definition ] = {}
// => result == { Foo : {} }

theme[ sprite ] = { img : "BAZ" }
// => theme == { Bar : { img : "BAZ" } }

result[ definition ].data = theme[ sprite ];
// => result == { Foo : {
//                  data : { img : "BAZ" }
//                }
//              }

result[ definition ].img  = theme[ sprite ].img;
// => result == { Foo : {
//                  data : { img : "BAZ" },
//                  img  : "BAZ"
//                }
//              }

delete result[ definition ].data.img;

console.log( result.[ definition ].data.img );
// => undefined


console.log( theme[ sprite ].img );
// => undefined

console.log( result[ definition ].img
// => "BAZ"
```